# How to use Authorization for tenant configuration Azure Apimanagement

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to use this method for deploying my ApiManagement Settings from a my Git repository.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/tenantconfiguration/deploy

But (of course) I am asked for a authorization token.

I cant figure out where to find/create this token?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to call APIM management API. One is to go through ARM - calling URLs that start with management.azure.com. This way you're relying on Azure authentication, it's RBAC rules, and the regular wayt to authenticate to Azure apply here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#create-the-request. This is recommended way. This is the same API that is used by Azure PowerShell.

APIM does offer another way though called Direct API. This is optionally enabled in Management API page. There as well you can generate a SAS token that to can put into Authorization header while making a call. For this to work you need to call APIM API directly via .management.azure-api.net. Base URI for your service is displayed on the same page.

Comment: I found this key that looks like this SharedAccessSignature integration&201809080619&DmQUx1..... But I get an error saying Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is provided in an invalid format.

Comment: My mistake, misunderstood the question. Edited the answer.